# Undefined when trying to get querystring values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can anyone spot the reason why out of the 3 querystring parameters, 2 get values and 1 is undefined.

```
<li class="@ViewBag.ShowNext">@Html.RouteLink("Next »", "Search", new { page = @ViewBag.NextPage, q = @ViewBag.TextClean, Option = @ViewBag.Option }, new { id = "frmPageNext" })</li>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
var vars = [], QStrings;
var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
if (q != undefined) {
    q = q.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
        QStrings = q[i].split('='); vars.push(QStrings[1]);
        vars[QStrings[0]] = QStrings[1];
    }
}

$('#frmPageNext').live('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Results")',
        data: { "q": vars['q'], "page": vars['page'], "Option": vars['Option'] },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(vars['q']);
            alert(vars['page']); //Returning undefined
            alert(vars['Option']);
            $("#dvSearchLeft").html(data).fadeIn(300);
        }
    });        
});
```

-------------------------URL MVC-----------------

```
<a href="/Search-Results-For/Hotels/Web/2" id="frmPageNext">Next &#187;</a>

The above would be <a href="/Search-Results-For/q=Hotels&Option=Web&Page=2
```

----------------Current Code--------------------

I have tried moving the javascript around trying to get the code to work, but keep getting undefined for all 3 parameters

```
<script>



        $('#frmPageNext').live('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var vars = [], QStrings;
            var q = $('#frmPageNext').attr('href').split('?')[1];
            if (q != undefined) {
                q = q.split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
                    QStrings = q[i].split('='); vars.push(QStrings[1]);
                    vars[QStrings[0]] = QStrings[1];
                }
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Results")',
                type: 'Get',
                data: { "q": vars['q'], "Page": vars['page'], "Option": vars['Option'] },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(vars['q']);
                    alert(vars['page']);
                    alert(vars['Option']);
                    $("#dvSearchLeft").html(data).fadeIn(300);
                }
            });


        });

    </script>
```

Comment: If you posted the actual characters in the URL's, and not the serverside language, it would probably be easier for people to see what's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of case : try to use `vars['Page']` instead of `vars['page']`.

This of course is if you have a `Page` variable in your url parameters. Otherwise you will get an `undefined` from your `vars` array.

[Edit after comment]
So if I get right what you want to achieve is to transform : `"/Search-Results-For/Hotels/Web/2"` into an ajax query String. Then you would do something like :

```
var splittedHref = $('#frmPageNext').attr('href').split("/");
var q = splittedHref[2];
var Option = splittedHref[3];
var Page = splittedHref[4];
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("Results")',
  type: 'Get',
  data: { "q": q,"Page": Page, "Option": Option },...
```

Does this solve your problem ?

Comment: Tried both examples, still page is undefined

Comment: In Chrome this is how the url looks once the link is clicked, page is not displayed http://localhost:50435/Search-Results-For?q=hotels&Option=Web

Comment: Then that explain why the `vars['page']` is undefined in your javascript. It is another matter to check why the page parameter does not appear in your url.

Comment: Yes but when I hover mouse over link, I can see the number 2 for page, but once clicked the value is not getting picked up

Comment: Found the problem but no idea how to fix it. My javascript is getting the values from the browser url, I need to get the value from the link url. I have modified code slightly and put all javascript inside click event, but that does not seem to fix the problem. How can I get querystring params from link not browser url

Comment: Hi benzonico, still getting undefined, is it something I'm doing, I have added updated code

Comment: ok i'm just getting now what you are trying to achieve... hold on.

Comment: Hi benzonico I'm trying to do a partial page update when the link is clicked, but for some reason it just is not working, i'm in the process of trying to debug the problem

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, case is important. `page` is not the same as `Page`.

I would suggest replacing this line:

```
vars[QStrings[0]] = QStrings[1];
```

With this one:

```
vars[QStrings.shift().toLowerCase()] = QStrings.join("=");
```

Note that this also handles the edge case where there are unencoded `=` signs in the value itself.

Then just make sure you update the `data: {"q".....` line to only use lowercase letters.

Comment: Hi benzonico sorry all variables are now undefined